Update error KDE Plasma Discoverer
When I want to update Plasma Discoverer this gets prompted to me. I don't understand why. I'm trying to update 2.5 GB of stuff, and this is a headache.

When I run the sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade command I get 1200 packages that cannot be upgraded for some reason, and apparently KDE Plasma is the only place where the error is shown.
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade output:
rufus07@1971:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for rufus07: 
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                                                    
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                           
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease    
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease  
Get:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security InRelease [7.529 B]
Get:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-updates InRelease [7.468 B]
Get:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-security InRelease [7.462 B]
Get:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-updates InRelease [7.461 B]
Fetched 29,9 kB in 1s (21,1 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1236 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  accountsservice accountwizard adb aisleriot akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator alsa-ucm-conf
  alsa-utils amd64-microcode android-libbase android-libcutils android-liblog apache2 apache2-bin
  apache2-data apache2-utils appmenu-gtk3-module appstream apt apt-utils apturl apturl-common ark
  at-spi2-core avahi-daemon avahi-utils avrdude baloo-kf5 baobab bc bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs
  bluedevil blueman bluez bluez-cups bluez-obexd bolt breeze breeze-cursor-theme brltty bup cabextract calc
  calc-common chafa cheese colord coreutils cups cups-browsed cups-bsd cups-client cups-core-drivers
  cups-daemon cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers cups-ipp-utils cups-pk-helper cups-ppdc curl dconf-cli
  dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service debconf-kde-data debconf-kde-helper default-jre default-jre-headless
  deja-dup desktop-file-utils dirmngr dleyna-server dnsmasq-base dolphin dolphin-plugins dragonplayer
  drkonqi duplicity dvisvgm e2fsprogs efibootmgr enchant-2 eog espeak-ng-data evince evolution-data-server
  fdisk ffmpeg ffmpegthumbs file file-roller flatpak fluidsynth fprintd frameworkintegration freerdp2-x11
  fuseiso fwupd gawk gcr gdb gdm3 gedit gedit-common geoclue-2.0 ghostscript gimp gimp-data
  gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-adw-1 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4
  gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0
  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtk-4.0 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0
  gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 git
  git-man gjs gkbd-capplet glib-networking glib-networking:i386 glib-networking-services gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-calculator gnome-calendar gnome-characters gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-initial-setup gnome-keyring
  gnome-keyring-pkcs11 gnome-logs gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines gnome-online-accounts gnome-power-manager
  gnome-remote-desktop gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
  gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
  gnome-shell-extensions gnome-startup-applications gnome-sudoku gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal-data gnome-themes-extra gnome-todo gnome-tweaks gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gnupg2
  gnustep-base-common gnustep-base-runtime gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv
  graphviz grilo-plugins-0.3-base grilo-plugins-0.3-extra grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
  gsasl-common gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-fdkaac
  gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-packagekit gstreamer1.0-pipewire
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-vaapi gstreamer1.0-x
  gstreamer1.0-x:i386 gtk-update-icon-cache gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf guile-2.2-libs
  guile-3.0-libs gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs gwenview hplip hplip-data
  ibus ibus-data ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-gtk4 iio-sensor-proxy imagemagick-6.q16 initramfs-tools
  initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core iproute2 jp2a juk jupyter-qtconsole kaccounts-providers
  kactivitymanagerd kaddressbook kamera kate kcalc kde-baseapps kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data
  kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-screenlocker kde-config-sddm kde-config-updates kde-plasma-desktop
  kde-spectacle kde-standard kde-style-breeze kde-style-oxygen-qt5 kdeconnect kded5 kdegraphics-thumbnailers
  kdepim-addons kdepim-runtime kdepim-themeeditors kdeplasma-addons-data kdialog keditbookmarks kerneloops
  kf5-messagelib-data kfind kgamma5 khelpcenter khotkeys khotkeys-data kimageformat-plugins kinfocenter
  kinit kio kio-extras kio-extras-data kio-ldap kitty kleopatra kmail kmailtransport-akonadi kmenuedit kmod
  knotes konq-plugins konqueror konsole konsole-kpart korganizer kpackagelauncherqml kpackagetool5
  kpeople-vcard kross kscreen ksshaskpass ksystemstats ktexteditor-data ktexteditor-katepart ktnef
  kup-backup kwalletmanager kwayland-data kwayland-integration kwin-common kwin-data kwin-style-breeze
  kwin-x11 kwrite kwrited latte-dock layer-shell-qt libaccounts-glib0 libaccountsservice0 libadwaita-1-0
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libappmenu-gtk3-parser0 libappstream-glib8 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap libasound2-plugins libasound2-plugins:i386 libatk-adaptor libatk-wrapper-java-jni
  libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libavahi-client3 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3 libavahi-common3:i386 libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libavcodec-extra
  libayatana-appindicator3-1 libayatana-ido3-0.4-0 libayatana-indicator3-7 libbabeltrace1 libboost-dev
  libboost-regex1.74.0 libcairo-gobject-perl libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo-perl
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2 libcairo2:i386 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse
  libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclone-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
  libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcolorcorrect5 libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcryptsetup12
  libcub-dev libcupti-dev libcurand10 libcusolver11 libcusolvermg11 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdbusmenu-glib4
  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdconf1 libdebconf-kde1 libdecor-0-0 libdecor-0-0:i386 libdecor-0-plugin-1-cairo
  libdecor-0-plugin-1-cairo:i386 libdee-1.0-4 libdleyna-connector-dbus-1.0-1 libdolphinvcs5 libegl-mesa0
  libegl-mesa0:i386 libenchant-2-2 libepub0 libespeak-ng1 libfaudio0 libfido2-1 libfile-fcntllock-perl
  libflite1 libfluidsynth3 libfprint-2-2 libfreetype6 libfreetype6:i386 libfwupd2 libgail-common libgbm1
  libgbm1:i386 libgcab-1.0-0 libgck-1-0 libgcr-base-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgd3 libgd3:i386 libgdata22
  libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdm1 libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue-2-0
  libgexiv2-2 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g libgl1-amber-dri libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib-perl libglib2.0-bin
  libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth-3.0-13 libgnome-games-support-1-3
  libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0b libgpod-common libgrilo-0.3-0 libgsettings-qt1 libgsf-1-114
  libgspell-1-2 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
  libgtk-4-1 libgtk-4-bin libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgtksourceview-4-0 libgtop-2.0-11 libgts-bin
  libgudev-1.0-0 libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-4 libgusb2 libgvc6 libhandy-1-0 libharfbuzz0b
  libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhfstospell11 libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl libhttp-message-perl libibus-1.0-5
  libimobiledevice6 libinput10 libinstpatch-1.0-2 libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjcat1
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjxr-tools libk5crypto3 libk5crypto3:i386 libkaccounts2 libkcolorpicker0
  libkdecorations2-5v5 libkf5akonadisearch-bin libkf5akonadisearch-plugins libkf5baloo5 libkf5balooengine5
  libkf5baloowidgets-bin libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5calendarutils-bin
  libkf5configwidgets-data libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5 libkf5dav-data
  libkf5dav5 libkf5declarative-data libkf5declarative5 libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data
  libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5grantleetheme-plugins libkf5guiaddons-data libkf5guiaddons5 libkf5i18n-data
  libkf5i18n5 libkf5i18nlocaledata5 libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5iconthemes5
  libkf5idletime5 libkf5incidenceeditor-bin libkf5jsapi5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5
  libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin libkf5khtml-bin
  libkf5khtml-data libkf5khtml5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiogui5 libkf5kiontlm5
  libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5kirigami2-5 libkf5konq6 libkf5krosscore5 libkf5krossui5
  libkf5messageviewer-plugins libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5
  libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5package-data libkf5package5 libkf5parts-data
  libkf5parts-plugins libkf5parts5 libkf5people-data libkf5people5 libkf5peoplebackend5 libkf5peoplewidgets5
  libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libkf5prison5 libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5purpose-bin libkf5purpose5
  libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5runner5 libkf5screen-bin libkf5service-bin libkf5service-data libkf5service5
  libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5style5
  libkf5su-bin libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkf5sysguard-data libkf5texteditor-bin libkf5texteditor5
  libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5unitconversion-data libkf5unitconversion5 libkf5wallet-bin
  libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5 libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5xmlgui-bin
  libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5 libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5 libkgantt2 libkimageannotator-common
  libkimageannotator0 libkmod2 libkolabxml1v5 libkpathsea6 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0
  libkrb5support0:i386 libkscreenlocker5 libksgrd9 libksysguardformatter1 libksysguardsensorfaces1
  libksysguardsensors1 libksysguardsystemstats1 libkwalletbackend5-5 libkworkspace5-5
  liblayershellqtinterface5 libldb2 liblocale-gettext-perl liblouisutdml-bin liblqr-1-0 libmagic-mgc
  libmalcontent-0-0 libmanette-0.2-0 libmariadb3 libmath-random-isaac-xs-perl libmediaart-2.0-0
  libmessaging-menu0 libmm-glib0 libmtp-runtime libmysqlclient21 libnet-dbus-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
  libnice10 libnm0 libnma-common libnma0 libnode-dev libnotificationmanager1 libnotify-bin libnotify4
  libnsl2 libnsl2:i386 libnss-nisplus:i386 libnss-systemd libnvidia-ml-dev libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm4 liboauth0
  libodbc2 libodbc2:i386 libodbccr2 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenal1:i386 libopenconnect5
  libopenmpt-modplug1 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libostree-1-1 liboxygenstyle5-5 liboxygenstyleconfig5-5
  libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpackagekitqt5-1 libpam-fprintd libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-systemd
  libpango-1.0-0 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpcaudio0 libpcre3 libpeas-1.0-0
  libpipewire-0.3-modules libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libplymouth5 libpolkit-agent-1-0
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpolkit-qt5-1-1 libpowerdevilcore2 libpowerdevilui5 libpq5 libprocesscore9
  libprocessui9 libproxy-tools libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libproxy1v5
  libproxy1v5:i386 libptexenc1 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0:i386 libpython3-dev
  libpython3-stdlib libqapt3 libqapt3-runtime libqca-qt5-2 libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy
  libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5hunspellinputmethod5 libqt5keychain1 libqt5location5 libqt5multimedia5
  libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediagsttools5 libqt5multimediaquick5 libqt5multimediawidgets5
  libqt5networkauth5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5positioningquick5 libqt5qml5 libqt5qmlmodels5
  libqt5qmlworkerscript5 libqt5quick5 libqt5quickcontrols2-5 libqt5quickparticles5 libqt5quickshapes5
  libqt5quicktemplates2-5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5script5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5serialport5
  libqt5sql5-mysql libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5 libqt5texttospeech5 libqt5virtualkeyboard5
  libqt5waylandclient5 libqt5waylandcompositor5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webengine-data libqt5webengine5
  libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5websockets5 libqt5x11extras5
  libqt5xmlpatterns5 libraptor2-0 libraqm0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common
  libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-common
  libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-it libreoffice-impress libreoffice-l10n-it libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-writer librhythmbox-core10 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librtmp1 librtmp1:i386 libsane-common
  libsane-hpaio libsane1 libsane1:i386 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsasl2-modules-db libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit libscim8v5 libsdl-image1.2
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsecret-1-0 libserf-1-1 libshout3 libshout3:i386
  libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsndfile1 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0 libsndio7.0:i386
  libsocket6-perl libspa-0.2-modules libspectre1 libspeechd2 libssh-4 libssh-4:i386 libssl-dev
  libsub-name-perl libsvn1 libsynctex2 libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 libtalloc2 libtaskmanager6 libtdb1
  libtexlua53 libtexluajit2 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libthrust-dev libtotem-plparser18
  libtotem0 libtracker-sparql-3.0-0 libudev1 libudev1:i386 libudisks2-0 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity9
  libupower-glib3 libuv1-dev libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9 libvncclient1 libvncserver1 libvoikko1
  libvolume-key1 libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwacom9 libwbclient0
  libweather-ion7 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwhoopsie0 libwine libwine:i386 libwmf-0.2-7 libwmf-0.2-7-gtk
  libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libxaw7 libxklavier16 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-parser-perl libxmlb2
  libxsimd-dev libyelp0 libzmq5 libzvbi-common linux-firmware linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic
  linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic lsof mailutils mailutils-common man-db mbox-importer mesa-va-drivers
  mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 milou modemmanager
  mokutil mousetweaks nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal nautilus-sendto
  nautilus-share netpbm netplan.io network-manager network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome nmap nmap-common node-cacache node-chalk node-hosted-git-info node-lru-cache
  nodejs npm nsight-compute-target nsight-systems-target ntfs-3g nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-gdb
  nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-profiler nvidia-visual-profiler okular okular-extra-backends openjdk-11-jre
  openjdk-11-jre-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless openssh-client openssl openvpn orca
  packagekit packagekit-tools parted partitionmanager perl perl-base perl-openssl-defaults phonon4qt5
  phonon4qt5-backend-vlc pim-data-exporter pim-sieve-editor pinentry-gnome3 pipewire pipewire-bin pkexec
  plasma-browser-integration plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-desktop plasma-desktop-data plasma-discover
  plasma-discover-backend-fwupd plasma-discover-backend-snap plasma-discover-common plasma-disks
  plasma-framework plasma-integration plasma-nm plasma-pa plasma-runners-addons plasma-systemmonitor
  plasma-thunderbolt plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace plasma-workspace-data
  plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-spinner plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text policykit-1 polkit-kde-agent-1
  polkitd polybar poppler-utils postfix power-profiles-daemon powerdevil powerdevil-data ppp
  printer-driver-c2esp printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-hpcups
  printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-splix procps pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gsettings pulseaudio-utils python3 python3-anyio python3-apt
  python3-brlapi python3-brotli python3-cairo python3-cap-ng python3-cffi-backend python3-coverage
  python3-cryptography python3-cups python3-dbus python3-dev python3-distupgrade python3-evdev
  python3-fonttools python3-fuse python3-gdbm python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-gpg python3-greenlet
  python3-ibus-1.0 python3-ipython python3-jsonschema python3-keyring python3-kiwisolver python3-ldb
  python3-lib2to3 python3-lxml python3-lz4 python3-magic python3-markupsafe python3-matplotlib
  python3-minimal python3-netifaces python3-numpy python3-openssl python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk
  python3-pluggy python3-protobuf python3-pylibacl python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia
  python3-pyqt5.qtopengl python3-pyqt5.qtpositioning python3-pyqt5.qtquick python3-pyqt5.qtsensors
  python3-pyqt5.qtserialport python3-pyqt5.qtsql python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qttexttospeech
  python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets
  python3-pyqt5.qtxmlpatterns python3-pyqt5.sip python3-pyrsistent python3-pytest python3-pythran
  python3-pyxattr python3-qtconsole python3-qtpy python3-reportlab python3-samba python3-scipy
  python3-setproctitle python3-software-properties python3-sqlalchemy python3-sqlalchemy-ext python3-systemd
  python3-talloc python3-tdb python3-tk python3-unicodedata2 python3-uno python3-update-manager
  python3-xapian python3-yaml python3-zmq python3-zope.interface qdbus-qt5 qml-module-gsettings1.0
  qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop qml-module-org-kde-kcm qml-module-org-kde-kconfig
  qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons qml-module-org-kde-kio qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2
  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons qml-module-org-kde-ksysguard
  qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem qml-module-org-kde-newstuff qml-module-org-kde-people
  qml-module-org-kde-prison qml-module-org-kde-purpose qml-module-org-kde-qqc2desktopstyle
  qml-module-org-kde-runnermodel qml-module-org-kde-solid qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel
  qml-module-qt-labs-platform qml-module-qt-labs-qmlmodels qml-module-qt-labs-settings
  qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtqml qml-module-qtqml-models2
  qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-particles2 qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets
  qml-module-qtquick-shapes qml-module-qtquick-templates2 qml-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard
  qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 qml-module-qtwebengine qsynth qt5-gtk-platformtheme
  qt5-image-formats-plugins qtspeech5-flite-plugin qtspeech5-speechd-plugin qtvirtualkeyboard-plugin
  qtwayland5 remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-plugins rsync ruby rygel samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  sane-airscan sane-utils sbsigntool scrcpy sddm sddm-theme-debian-maui seahorse session-migration
  shared-mime-info shotwell shotwell-common signon-plugin-oauth2 simple-scan simplescreenrecorder smbclient
  socat software-properties-common software-properties-gtk software-properties-qt sonnet-plugins
  speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng spice-vdagent sshfs
  steam:i386 subversion sudo sweeper switcheroo-control system-config-printer-udev systemd systemd-hwe-hwdb
  systemd-oomd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd systemsettings tcpdump texlive-base texlive-binaries thermald
  thunderbird thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us thunderbird-locale-it tnftp totem totem-plugins
  tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs transmission-common transmission-gtk
  ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-pro-client ubuntu-pro-client-l10n ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session udev udisks2 unar uno-libs-private update-manager
  update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common upower ure virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
  virtualbox-qt vlc vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt
  vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-video-splitter
  vlc-plugin-visualization w3m w3m-img wget whoopsie whoopsie-preferences wine32:i386 wine64 wireless-tools
  wpasupplicant x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xdg-dbus-proxy
  xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-desktop-portal-kde
  xdg-user-dirs-gtk xserver-xorg-input-libinput xwayland yaru-theme-gnome-shell yaru-theme-icon yelp zenity
  zlib1g zlib1g:i386 zlib1g-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1236 not upgraded.


Please post the full output of sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade by editing the question

https://pastebin.com/2phSVfF3 here it is

These updates are kept back (google phased updates in Ubuntu to know why). They should become available in a few days. If it does not work after a week, please ping us here.

Thanks friend, I'll let you know on monday? Maybe tuesday, because it has been a couple of days.

Sure. Hope it would be fixed by then
